# How to access the table from the Data Source in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm building a very simple Login Application by using local database. I create a Service-base call EmployeeDB in my project. In EmployeeDB, I create a table call Employee which has 2 columns, one is Username and Password. Next, I connect my EmployeeDB to my form. Let's say I'm trying to compare the user input to the first row value of the table Employee.

```
foreach (DataRow row in EmployeeDBDataSet.Employee)
{
    if(row.ItemArray[0] == username && row.ItemArray[1] == password)
    {
        // Do whatever I want in here
    }
}
```

However, it gives me error at `DataRow row in EmployeeDBDataSet.Employee`...How am I going to access the table Employee from my EmployeeDBDataSet ? Thanks

Comment: What is the error? Is it an exception? what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know what the name of the column is, this always works for me and, if employee is the table, you should do table.rows

```
foreach(DataRow row in EmployeeDBDataSet.Employee.Rows)
    {
        if(row["Your column"].ToString() == password)
        {
            // code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not referencing to the correct data type. Maybe you need to do something like this. Create a class which has the same data set as your employee

```
foreach (cEmployee employee in EmployeeDBDataSet.Employee)
{
    if(row.ItemArray[0] == username && row.ItemArray[1] == password)
    {
        // Do whatever I want in here
    }
}
```